# Can't download npm packages for kendo ui components (angular 2)

Tags: angular, npm, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I've been using the alpha/beta components of kendo ui for angular 2 (CLI) for at least 3 months. I had no issues in downloading the packages for each component.

Just yesterday, downloading the kendo ui packages failed. I'm totally lost. I've cleared the npm/node cache, reinstalled node, I've subscribed and signed in to progress again. Still no success.

The error messages I get from the console when calling npm install:

```
...
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
...
```

[image]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "genesis-ui",
  "version": "1.7.0",
  "description": "Bootstrap 4 Admin Template",
  "author": "",
  "url": "https://genesisui.com",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.18.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^0.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.27.8",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.18.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.9.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.20.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^0.8.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^0.13.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.11.15",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "angular-calendar": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.5.2",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.0.6",
    "angular2-toaster": "2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "cldr-data": "^30.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.6",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ckeditor": "0.0.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/quill": "0.0.29",
    "@types/tinymce": "^4.5.0",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.25.5",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.3.1",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
  }
}
```

This is my .npmrc file:

```
@progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
//registry.npm.telerik.com/:_authToken=D[NINJA CONTENT]EPI/AcK[NINJA CONTENT]
```

Any idea on how to make kendo ui package download available again?

P.S. Download of packages that are not Progress/kendo ui have no problem in being downloaded. And yes, I have logged in, by the cmd

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

Comment: You probably haven'g logged in

Comment: yep, that is the first thing I've checked.

Comment: do you still have an active subscription?

Comment: I've got no subscription, I just signed up. From my understanding kendo ui is free, since it's in alpha/beta. Am I correct?

Comment: from what i remember, only a couple of modules are free and even then, you only get them for 30 days after signing up

Comment: I've check telerik website, as of today there are no prices for "kendo ui angular2", furthermore they are stating that "Final Release, Planned (May 2017)". The other odd thing is that I've download ng2 modules from telerik for at least 2 months, thus way more than 30 days. Hmmm.. This makes me wonder, very much.

Comment: actually there are prices for kendo ui angular2. and you can have them forever pretty much but you only have access to download each module and update for 30 days after signing up

Comment: I've basically made an application mostly based on kendo ui ng2 components. Not good at all.

Comment: this might help: http://www.telerik.com/purchase/kendo-ui

Comment: Ok I see it, "Native Angular 2 components" for Kendo UI
Professional.

Comment: Yeah, so youre gonna have to buy them to update them and use them in public applications

Comment: Just now I've run "npm install" add all the telerik kendo ui ng2 packages were downloaded (:-D). I don't know what was going on in these 3 days. Probably it was some issue with their servers. What matters now is that it works. I'll buy a subscription once my project is in alpha and they'll issue a final release.

Comment: I am currently faced with the same problem mate. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: @AakashThakur I've downloaded the npm packages and all works fine now. To clear things out with the subscription plans of telerik, at the moment I don't have any, I'm just signed up to their progress site. Since kendo ui for ng2 is not yet in a final version, I suppose, as they said, that the components can be downloaded without a subscription. The question is why last week I was not able to download the packages? I can only guess that it was an issue with their server.

Comment: Thats what I am saying. I am also having issues with downloading packages just like you. It must have to do something with their server right?